# reading json file in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I'm new to PySpark, Below is my JSON file format from kafka.

```
{
        "header": {
        "platform":"atm",
        "version":"2.0"
       }
        "details":[
       {
        "abc":"3",
        "def":"4"
       },
       {
        "abc":"5",
        "def":"6"
       },
       {
        "abc":"7",
        "def":"8"
       }    
      ]
    }
```

how can I read through the values of all `"abc"` `"def"` in details and add this is to a new list like this `[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8)]`. The new list will be used to create a spark data frame. how can i do this in pyspark.I tried the below code.

```
parsed = messages.map(lambda (k,v): json.loads(v))
list = []
summed = parsed.map(lambda detail:list.append((String(['mcc']), String(['mid']), String(['dsrc']))))
output = summed.collect()
print output
```

It produces the error '**too many values to unpack**'

Error message below at statement `summed.collect()`

> 16/09/12 12:46:10 INFO deprecation: mapred.task.is.map is deprecated.
>   Instead, use mapreduce.task.ismap 16/09/12 12:46:10 INFO deprecation:
>   mapred.task.partition is deprecated. Instead, use
>   mapreduce.task.partition 16/09/12 12:46:10 INFO deprecation:
>   mapred.job.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.id 16/09/12
>   12:46:10 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File
>   "/usr/hdp/2.3.4.0-3485/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py",
>   line 111, in main
>       process()   File "/usr/hdp/2.3.4.0-3485/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py",
>   line 106, in process
>       serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)   File
>   "/usr/hdp/2.3.4.0-3485/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py",
>   line 263, in dump_stream
>       vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))   File "", line 1, in  ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: what are the results of: messages.take(3) ,parsed = messages.map(lambda (k,v): json.loads(v)) ,  parsed.take(3) ?

Comment: in this  parsed = messages.map(lambda (k,v): json.loads(v)) statement i am getting error " too many values to unpack" because "details" has a list of json string

Comment: please provide the result of "messages.take(3)", please also provide the error you receive (you can edit your question and add this info)

Comment: Hi Yaron, please find the result of messages.take(3) below:

>>> messages.take(3)

[u'{', u'        "header": {', u'        "platform":"atm",']

I have updated the error message in the question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The `List` is not part of the RDD. The code is fundamentally wrong. You should take the correct entries from the details json-object, process them, and collect them to the driver in the very end.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, the json is invalid. After the header a `,` is missing.

That being said, lets take this json:

```
{"header":{"platform":"atm","version":"2.0"},"details":[{"abc":"3","def":"4"},{"abc":"5","def":"6"},{"abc":"7","def":"8"}]}
```

This can be processed by:

```
>>> df = sqlContext.jsonFile('test.json')
>>> df.first()
Row(details=[Row(abc='3', def='4'), Row(abc='5', def='6'), Row(abc='7', def='8')], header=Row(platform='atm', version='2.0'))

>>> df = df.flatMap(lambda row: row['details'])
PythonRDD[38] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:43

>>> df.collect()
[Row(abc='3', def='4'), Row(abc='5', def='6'), Row(abc='7', def='8')]

>>> df.map(lambda entry: (int(entry['abc']),     int(entry['def']))).collect()
[(3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @ Fokko Driesprong Hi Fokko Driesprong: I'm facing the below error: @step: df.collect() - it is failing with the below error: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last): vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch)) File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda> TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str o/p of df.first() is below: "Row(details=[Row(abc=u'3', def=u'4'), Row(abc=u'5', def=u'6'), Row(abc=u'7', def=u'8')], header=Row(platform=u'atm', version=u'2.0'))" I observed the values in the "details" are in Unicode. Should I do anything there? Thanks again!

Comment: What's your exact input? The contents of my file is:
`{"header":{"platform":"atm","version":"2.0"},"details":[{"abc":"3","def":"4"},{"abc":"5","def":"6"},{"abc":"7","def":"8"}]}`
Just a single line without newlines.

Comment: @ Fokko Driesprong yes am using the same input , in a single line without newlines.

Comment: @ Fokko Driesprong , also another quick question, can we do the same in spark RDD instead of Spark dataframe SQL? If so how can we traverse the array list in "details" part of the input

Comment: @anusha sure, all the operations are also available on a RDD. However, Spark 2.0 is moving more and more to the DataFrames, and moving away from the RDD. The trick that I did is using the `flatMap()`. Which flattens the JSON Array and so we get a major list of only all the details. If you want to traverse this for each message, you need to change it to `Map`. I would suggest you give it a try in the `pyspark` console.

Comment: @ Fokko Driesprong , thanks will try the same in pyspark console and will keep you updated. But when I try the above spark SQL , i am getting the list in Unicode, do I need to change this to ascii to over the above error?"Row(details=[Row(abc=u'3', def=u'4'), Row(abc=u'5', def=u'6'), Row(abc=u'7', def=u'8')], header=Row(platform=u'atm', version=u'2.0'))" I observed the values in the "details" are in Unicode. Should I do anything there? Thanks again!

Answer (score 8):

```
import pyspark
from pyspark import SparkConf

# You can configure the SparkContext

conf = SparkConf()
conf.set('spark.local.dir', '/remote/data/match/spark')
conf.set('spark.sql.shuffle.partitions', '2100')
SparkContext.setSystemProperty('spark.executor.memory', '10g')
SparkContext.setSystemProperty('spark.driver.memory', '10g')
sc = SparkContext(appName='mm_exp', conf=conf)
sqlContext = pyspark.SQLContext(sc)

data = sqlContext.read.json(file.json)
```

I feel that he missed an important part of the read sequence. You have to initialize a SparkContext.

When you start a SparkContext, it also spins up a webUI on port 4040. The webUI can be accessed using http://localhost:4040. That is a useful place to check progress of all calculations.

Answer (score 6):

try this with latest spark version.

```
df = spark.read.json('test.json')
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the info in the comments, each row in messages RDD holds one line from the json file

```
 u'{', 
 u' "header": {', 
 u' "platform":"atm",'
```

Your code is failing in the following line:

```
parsed = messages.map(lambda (k,v): json.loads(v))
```

Your code takes line like: '{' and try to convert it into key,value, and execute json.loads(value)

it is clear that python/spark won't be able to divide one char '{' into key-value pair.

The json.loads() command should be executed on a complete json data-object

This specific task might be accomplished easier with pure python