# How would I get the json key names by doing a string split here? (Python)

Tags: python

I have a json var:
       `[u'{"Average_Rating":3.75,"Number_Of_Users_Who_Have_Watched_This_Movie":90,"title":"Quiz Show (1994)"}']`

And I want to get the '3.75', '90' and 'Quiz Show (1994)'. I've tried doing:

```
  for i in var:
      i.split(":")[1:-3]
```

but it's not working. I'm sure this is something simple but just don't get how to use it properly! Could anyone please help?

EDIT:

Normally, I would just use the `json` library but I'm using Apache PySpark and there are a few issues around JSON - how can I do it using just string splitting?

Comment: You don't have a JSON var, you have a list with one unicode string in it (that contains JSON).

Comment: Oh I see, thank you. How can I get the respective values out of that?

Comment: Have you [read the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)?

Comment: Hi @WayneWerner, just made an edit.

Comment: @xn139 you might want to add restrictions like that in your questions, perhaps even in the form of tags. With the generic python tags you can still add 4 more if you feel that they can help localize your question.

Comment: `PySpark applications are executed using a standard CPython interpreter in order to support Python modules that use C extensions.` Does PySpark really have problems with the JSON module?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39467501/344286 may be of some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get information from a JSON string, you should really use `json` for this.

```
var = [u'{"Average_Rating":3.75,"Number_Of_Users_Who_Have_Watched_This_Movie":90,"title":"Quiz Show (1994)"}']
import json

for i in var:
    print json.loads(i)["Average_Rating"]
```

### Per request of the original poster:

```
var = [u'{"Average_Rating":3.75,"Number_Of_Users_Who_Have_Watched_This_Movie":90,"title":"Quiz Show (1994)"}']

for i in var:
    print(i.split(":")[1].split(",")[0])
```

Comment: Hi, normally I would but I'm using Apache PySpark and there are a few issues around JSON - how can I do it using just string splitting?