# How to read JSON file with correct format in PySpark?

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a JSON file that looks like this:

```
{"id":{"0":0,"1":1,"2":2,"3":3}, "name":{"0":"name0","1":"name1","2":"name2","3":"name3"}}
```

When I read it using PySpark like:

```
names = spark.read.json('data/names.json')
```

I get all the rows into a single one, like this:

```
|            id|                name|
+--------------+--------------------+
|{0, 1, 2, 3...|{name1, name2, name3...
```

How can I read it so that the values are on multiple rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick hack can be to read the json with pandas like this:`pandas_df = pandas.read_json('data/names.json')` and then load it in spark `spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df)`.
For more comprehensive analysis of the problem check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39430868/reading-json-file-in-pyspark).

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative, more native Spark solution.

First, `explode_outer` to explode the `id` column and then get the corresponding `name` value.

```py
schema = StructType([
  StructField('id', MapType(StringType(), IntegerType())),
  StructField('name', MapType(StringType(), StringType()))
])

df = spark.read.json('data/names.json', schema=schema)
df = (df.select(F.explode_outer('id').alias('id_k', 'id_v'), 'name')
    .withColumn('name', F.col('name').getItem(F.col('id_v'))))
```